# Solving the system of differential equations for $c_1$ and $c_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

While reading the section "The General solution of the homogeneous equation" from *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes, Third Edition, by George F. Simmons*, it states:

> $$y''+P(x)y'+Q(x)y=0 \tag{1}$$
> Consequently, since $c_1y_1(x)+ c_2y_2(x)$ and $y(x)$ are both solutions of $(1)$ on
> $[a,b]$, it suffices to show that for some point $x_0$ in $[a,b]$ we can find $c_1$ and $c_2$ so
> that
> $$c_1y_1(x_0)+ c_2y_2(x_0)=y(x_0)$$
> and
> $$c_1y_1'(x_0)+ c_2y_2'(x_0)=y'(x_0)$$
> For this system to be solvable for $c_1$ and $c_2$, it suffices that the determinant
> $$
> \begin{vmatrix}
> y_1(x_0) & y_2(x_0) \\
> y_1'(x_0) & y_2'(x_0) \\
> \end{vmatrix}=y_1(x_0)y_2'(x_0)-y_2(x_0)y_2'(x_0)
> $$
> have a value different from zero. This leads us to investigate the function of $x$ defined by
> $$W(y_1,y_2)=y_1y_2'-y_2y_1'$$
> which is known as the *Wronskian* of $y_1$ and $y_2$, with special reference to whether it vanishes at $x_0$.

I still don't understand how he came up with this determinant

Comment: He simply says that non-singularity of the coefficient matrix of the system of equations is needed. Isn't?

Comment: @AnotherUser I didn't understand the response in the link you shared. Could you give me the name of the theorem so I can search for it on my own?

Comment: It has no name. It's simply the theorem that states that a system of $n$ linear equations in $n$ unknowns has one and only one solution if and only if the determinant of its matrix of coefficients is not $0$.